# Could a phoneGap app disable phone features such as email and text messaging?

Tags: cordova

I am hoping to create an app to help me focus and eliminate distractions by disabling certain cell phone features.

I don't have much experience with app development but I do have some javascript/html background.
I am wondering if the following would be possible using phonegap:

1. Disabling text messaging notifications during specific hours of the day and auto responding.
2. Disabling internet access to specific websites/domains.
3. Disabling email alerts
4. Putting the phone into airplane mode

I wasn't able to find an answer looking through the phonegap api and was hoping someone with experience with phonegap could save me a lot of time from potentially developing down a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PhoneGap allows you to add [plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) to an existing projects you can do anything you could do in a native, Objective C based application. But the idea behind PhoneGap is to write once and deploy on multiple devices, and if you are going to customize the application for iOS then you might as well write an actual iOS application.